# passing a char 2d array into a void function in c

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm new to c but I have been trying for ages to try and get this to work even though it seems so simple.

So below is what I am aiming to do which is working but I want to make 2 functions: fillseats() and printseatingplan()[for now I just want them all blank];

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char seatingplan[15][15];

    memset(seatingplan,'.',sizeof seatingplan);
    
    for (int k = 0; k < 15; ++k)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; ++j)
        {
            printf("%c",seatingplan[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So whenever I try to run these functions without pointers it gives me these �`:�ij:�
i�d:�iH@=�i
�B��ik:�

how can i use pointers to fix this

can I pass this array into the functions where printseatingplan()

```
void printseatingplan(char array[15][15])
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 15; ++k)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; ++j)
        {
            printf("%c",array[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and then fillseats() does:

```
void fillseats(char array[15][15])
{
    memset(array,'.',sizeof array);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof array` is the size of a char-pointer. It is **not** the size of the array. Consequently `memset(array,'.',sizeof array);` is not doing what you expect. You have to pass the size as an extra argument to the function.

Comment: The code you posted has very obvious syntax errors.  Please edit to fix.  Specifically function definitions are missing the closing `)`.  Regarding _"So whenever I try to make these functions I get errors"_, be explicit about what errors you are seeing.  Edit the exact text into your post.

Comment: BTW: With good compiler options you should have had a warning like: `warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'array' will return size of 'char (*)[15]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]` that told the problem

Comment: @SupportUkraine so if I used a pointer to the array I could still use sizeof?

Comment: @goomba No... when you pass an array all information about array size is gone. This is because the array is converted to a pointer to the first element. So in C you need to pass the size as an extra argument. Like: `void fillseats(size_t sz, char array[][15])`

Comment: @goomba It's a very common beginner mistake in C to use `sizeof someArray` inside functions. It fails. The only place where you can take the size of an array is in the function where you defined the array. See this simple example: https://ideone.com/EfAipt Notice how the size is printed correctly from `main` where the arrays are defined but incorrectly inside the functions. The functions print the size of a pointer instead of the size of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof` will give you only the size of the pointer, not the whole array.

You need to pass the sizes to the function. I would use **pointer to array**:

```
void fillseats(size_t rows, size_t cols, char (*array)[cols])
{
    memset(array,'.',rows * sizeof(*array));
}

void printseatingplan(size_t rows, size_t cols, char (*array)[cols])
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            printf("%c",array[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I call this function in the main would the inputs just be 15,15,array?

Comment: @goomba `fillseats(15,15,array);`

Comment: @goomba The "strange" syntax `char (*array)[cols]` means "pointer to char array with cols elements". Strictly this is the correct way of writing it. However, C allows another form (that by many is considered easier to understand). You can just write `char array[][cols]` It means the same. Which you prefer is a matter of taste.

Comment: @goomba Also notice that the code here is using Variable Length Array. It's the `[cols]` that requires VLA. While most compilers do support VLA, it's not required by the C standard any longer.

Comment: @SupportUkraine it is not the truth. In new C2x support for automatic VLAs is not compulsory, VLA array pointers is.

Comment: thanks for all the help!! that char array[][cols] makes a lot of sense too it works now!

Comment: @goomba - Saying _"Thanks"_ here is easily said by up-clicking or accepting answer

Answer (score 0):

`char array[15][15]` when used as parameter to a function "decays" into a pointer to the first element, in this case equivalent to `char (*array)[15])`. If you do  `sizeof array` instead the function, you get the size of a pointer (4 or 8 etc). If you do `sizeof *array` you just get the size of one dimension, 15.

A simple way to fix it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fillseats (size_t x, size_t y, char array[x][y])
{
    memset(array, '.', sizeof(char[x][y]));
}

void printseatingplan (size_t x, size_t y, char array[x][y])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    char seatingplan[15][15];

    fillseats(15, 15, seatingplan);
    printseatingplan(15, 15, seatingplan);
}
```

Comment: I would use objects not types in `sizeof`

Comment: @0___________ This is the perfect example of why that isn't always a good idea. See my answer [here](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285898/285910#answer-285910), scroll down to "Why sizeof *p isn't some universally great style".

Comment: @0___________ hmmm... how? The whole point is that you can't use `array` with `sizeof` inside a function

Comment: And the bottom line is, whenever you take the size of something, just make sure you know what you are doing. Don't dogmatically use a certain style without thinking and then assume your code is correct because you like that particular style so much.

Comment: @Lundin how? - https://godbolt.org/z/34xMqo9G3. *`Don't dogmatically use a certain style`* - I will not comment

Answer (score 0):

The size of array is bound to its type. The problem is that the parameters of array type decay to pointers. To prevent it, you can pass a pointer to an array. The pointer don't decay thus the essential part of the array type prevails.

```
void printseatingplan(char (*array)[15][15])
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 15; ++k)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; ++j)
        {
            printf("%c", (*array)[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fillseats(char (*array)[15][15])
{
    memset(*array,'.',sizeof *array);
}

int main (void)
{
    char seatingplan[15][15];

    fillseats(&seatingplan);
    printseatingplan(&seatingplan);
}
```